# Multiple seleccion con mouse en Datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un Datagridview **DGV_Historial_Ventas** con los registros de ventas y otro **DGV_Historial_Ventas_Articulos** con los artículos de la venta seleccionada en la primera (DGV_Historial_Ventas)

El DGV_Historial_Ventas tiene la propiedad **multirow**, es decir que puedo elegir varias ventas para que en el DGV_Historial_Ventas_Articulos se muestran todos los artículos que pertenezcan a esas ventas.

Todo funciona perfecto, cuando selecciono varias filas con CTRL o con SHIFT. Pero si hago una seleccion con el mouse (arrastrando y soltando) no se dispara el evento:

```
    Private Sub DGV_Ventas_Historial_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_Ventas_Historial.CellClick

    If DGV_Ventas_Historial.RowCount > 0 And DGV_Ventas_Historial.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        LlenaTablaVentahistorialArticulo(DGV_Ventas_Historial.SelectedRows)
        LlenaGridVentaHistorialArticulo(DGV_Ventas_Historial_Articulos)

        Label_Ventas_HistorialArticulos_Total.Text = "Total: " & DGV_Ventas_Historial.Item("TotalArticulos", e.RowIndex).Value.ToString & " Articulos"
    Else
        If DGV_Ventas_Historial.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then DGV_Ventas_Historial_Articulos.DataSource = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Pense en usar el evento **MouseUp** pero utiliza **e as DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs** el cual tiene coordenadas del mouse y no se como usarlo.

En CellClick utiliza **e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs** con lo cual puedo utilizar **e.rowindex** para saber la fila que se esta clickeando (que es algo que necesito)

Comment: Prueba con el evento de `SelectionChanged` Se deberia disparar con qualquier cambio de seleccion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El controlador del evento MouseUp no recibe un objeto DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs (que sí tienes propiedades RowIndex y ColumnIndex), si no un objeto MouseEventArgs (que efectivamente no las tiene).

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Utilizar el evento CellMouseUp cuyo controlador sí recibe un objeto DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs mediante el que puedes acceder a la fila y columna en la que se ha generado el evento
2. Utilizar el evento MouseUp y obtener la información de la celda en la que se produce utilizando el método HitTest del DataGridView que te proporciona un objeto HitTestInfo con información de la fila y columna ubicada en una posición determinada:

   ```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseUp
       Dim info As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
       Dim row = info.RowIndex
       Dim column = info.ColumnIndex
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Gracias! ya lo pude resolver siguiendo tu idea

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilice este método cuando quiero eliminar ,lo utilizo para máximo 5 objetos pero se podría usar una lista.

Llamo el metodo hacer click al botón de aceptar

```
Private Sub ElementosSeleccionados(aux As DataGridView)
    Dim id, i As Integer
    Dim idList(5)
    For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In aux.SelectedRows
        'show ids of multiple selected rows
        id = selectedItem.Cells("ID").Value
        idList(i) = id
        i += 1
    Next selectedItem
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    For Each elem As String In idList
        sResult &= elem & ", "
    Next
    MsgBox("Seleccionados" & sResult)
End Sub
```